# How to implement sectioned listview like in youtube app Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview

Does someone know to implement this kind of views structure in Android ? It's from youtube app.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android have a great little tool when you want to know how something was done.
It's the DDMS (device monitor), look around on Eclipse or Android Studio that you can find it.

Over there, you will find the option: "Dump View hierarchy for UIAutomator" and you can use it to get the View hierarchy of different apps. So for example YouTube:

[image]

You can see that it's just a normal ListView with a very cleverly built Adapter. Check out carefully the BaseAdapter class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

specially two methods:

```
int getViewTypeCount();
int getItemViewType(int position);
```

those can be used to have different types of view depending on the position of the ListView. So then it's just built one-by-one, the types you want to implement.

The "more" will do nothing more than add more items the data backing the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

happy coding...

Comment: I will try to see your suggestion and give you a feedback.

Comment: As I also saw in the DDMS, it's just a listview with the need of a good implementation for the BaseAdapter. You give me a good trick to learn more about views structure in other apps.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create more than 1 listview and use padding around it to create the space between one listview and another. You also need to make the layout where the listviews are setup scrollable.

I would personally setup a fragment for each listview to be able to load more data in each list.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Android doesn't work with more than one listView in the same vertical scrolling container. Please see my answer.

Comment: I already thought about your first suggestion by using nested listview. But it's not recommended like listview inside scrollview. I don't think that the second suggestion is good.